# Health Pickup System in Unity doesnt work and i will get an Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers

I make a script that detects if a HealthPickup has been triggered. If this is the case, it should check whether a certain script is present. If this is the case too, a function within this script should be accessed. But I get this error in the console:

> 'CharacterController' does not contain a definition for 'ChangeHealth'
> and no accessible extension method 'ChangeHealth' accepting a first
> argument of type 'CharacterController' could be found (are you missing
> a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My codes:

**CharacterController.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
Rigidbody2D rigidbody2d;
float horizontalmovement;
float verticalmovement;

//Playerstats Variabeln
int currentHealth;
int maxHealth = 5;

public float moveSpeed = 3.0f;

public void Start()
{
    rigidbody2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    currentHealth = 1;

}

public void Update()
{
    horizontalmovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    verticalmovement = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector2 position = rigidbody2d.position;

    position.x = position.x + moveSpeed * horizontalmovement * Time.deltaTime;
    position.y = position.y + moveSpeed * verticalmovement * Time.deltaTime;

    rigidbody2d.MovePosition(position);
}

public void ChangeHealth(int amount)
{
    currentHealth = Mathf.Clamp(currentHealth + amount, 0, maxHealth);
    Debug.Log(currentHealth + "/" + maxHealth);
}
 }
```

**GetHealth.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GetHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        CharacterController controller = other.GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        if(controller != null)
        {
            controller.ChangeHealth(1);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is trying to reference `CharacterController`, but the code you linked above that states the type is called `PlayerController`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was a dumb misstake, i know. But hey, i am working with unity only for one week :)